# Generating simple to compute permutation of sequence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have a sequence `0...N-1` and I wish to find some permutation $P : [0,N) \to [0,N)$  such that `P(0) ... P(N-1)` is a permutation of original sequence. P shall be easy to evaluate and either randomize sequence or at least put two consecutive elements apart, it can not be simple shift.

Would
$$P(i) = (i*K) \% N,$$
where $*$ is multiplication and $\%$ is modulus or remainder, do the trick for some $K's$?

Comment: For $P(i) = ((i\cdot K)\text{ mod }N)$ to be a permutation you need to have $\gcd(K, N) = 1$.

Comment: I was almost sure something like that holds, but the classes I had on that were some times ago :) Can you remind me how this is called or where I can find it?

Comment: I don't really know how you could find that specific thing. I guess you can study cyclic groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $K$ is coprime to $N$, your map is a permutation. This is because, for any $j \in [0,N)$, you will always be able to find an $i$ for which $i\times K\equiv j\pmod N$, which is a consequence of Bézout's lemma. In particular, if $N$ is prime, you can choose any $K$ between $2$ and $N-2$ inclusive.

If $N$ is not prime, so $N=pq$ where $p,q\ge 2$, then another mapping which works is
$$
f(i)=(i\;\%\;p)\times q + \lfloor i/p\rfloor
$$
Here is what this mapping is intuitively doing. Imagine taking a grid with $p$ rows and $q$ columns, and writing in that grid the numbers from $0$ to $N-1$, in the order left-to-right, top-to-bottom (the same way you write English). Then, you read out the numbers in a different order, where you read the numbers by columns top-to-bottom, left-to-right.